# How to install your custom flask extension

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying create custom flask extension and use it within my application. I'm using below project structure.

```
ExapmpleProject
--> apps
--> extensions
   -->flask-customext
      -->__init__.py
      -->flask_customext.py
      -->setup.py
--> sample.py
```

## sample.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import customext
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    if customext.validate():
        return 'Hello World!'
    else:
        return 'not allowed!'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I followed standard class based extension within `flask-customext` package as defined in the [extention dev doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/). How can I install this `customext` to be imported by `from flask.ext import customext` used in `sample.py` as any other flask-extensions does.

Not sure if this do the job but I tried `python setup.py install`. but it raised below error

```
error: package directory 'flask_customext' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/) says that

> Extensions are all located in a package called flask_something

Whereas in your example the package is named flask-customext, so it should be flask_customext.

Also id the [Extension Import Transition](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/#ext-import-transition) chapter it is recommended to use the new import convention:

```
import flask_something
```

Instead of:

```
import flask.ext.something
```